# Permanent Environment Variable for all users

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I want to have all users on the system to have an environment variable named SPI that points to /usr/local/share_ideas directory.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 17):

I'd put it in the /etc directory in the file `/etc/profile.d/myvariable.sh`. In this file I'd set it like this:

```
SPI=/usr/local/share_ideas
```

Files in the `/etc/profile.d` directory are automatically sourced as part of a user logging into the system. The files that end in a ".sh" are used by the bash shell.

Comment: Why not in `/etc/profile`? Is there a specific reason that using `/etc/profile.d` files is better?

Comment: In case the `/etc/profile` get's updated as a result of an update to an RPM. This is a remote issue but better to leave the system level files alone so your changes don't get lost.