# Where do I place commands to automatically be exported for all users?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, profile, dash

I have an embedded platform running an [Arago](http://arago-project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) linux distribution. Right now the only "user" is `root` but there will eventually be others, but I don't know how many or what user IDs they will have.

Every user of this system must have a particular environment variable exported in order for the GUI to work correctly. I found that if I created and then added the export command to `/home/root/.profile` it is set correctly for `root`.

Where should I place the command such that it is exported for every (current and future) user of the system?

Note: On my system, at start up there were no files present in `/home/root`, I added `.bash_profile` but that didn't work, then I added `.profile` and that did work. I thought I might have a dash shell because of that, but when I check `/bin/sh` it points to `bash`... so I tagged both.

Comment: `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile.d/...`

Comment: @Eddy_Em - Thanks.. so `/etc/bashrc` doesn't exist, but `/etc/profile.d/` does. There's a couple of shell scripts in there. I take it I just add another one that does an `export` and that will be autorun?

Comment: This isn't an unambiguous way: user can delete needed lines from his `~/.bashrc`. But you can replace `bash` by a script that will run bash with needed environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc)

Comment: @terdon - That's not a duplicate. That Question is how to get commands run for a *specific* user, which is why the Q and A's are all talking about `~/.profile`, that doesn't solve my problem because I need this command done for ***all current and future users***, which is why it needed to be done in the `/etc/profile.d/` area

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanent Environment Variable for all users](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74076/permanent-environment-variable-for-all-users)

Comment: I can't vote to close my question as a duplicate, but @Braiam that one looks right to me. This should be closed as a dup of that one, thanks for finding it. I figured someone would have asked the same but I didn't locate it in my searching.

Comment: You can VTC your own question. Just press the "close" button... wait, you don't have 1k rep :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the code in a new file in `/etc/profile.d/` and check that `/etc/profile` has some code that executes every script in that directory.

My `/etc/profile` has:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

which means the script **needs to have a `.sh` extension**

Comment: No, just replace `for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh` with `for i in /etc/profile.d/*`. But it will try to run also scripts for other shells (like csh or zsh).

Comment: @Eddy_Em if the OP has a script which has `*.sh`, touching that script is not a good idea. On the next update of `/etc/profile` it will get overwritten with one that uses that pattern again, and his script mysteriously would not work anymore.

Comment: Why not simply use `/etc/profile` itself? Why is it better to create a new file in `profile.d` and source it?

Comment: @terdon as I indicated in my previous comment to Eddy_Em /etc/profile might be overwritten with some system upgrade, depending on how it got on your computer in the first place. A new script in /etc/profile.d/is less likely to be overwritten. This is not theoretical, I have had that happen with SuSE Linux, although I am not sure if it was `/etc/profile` or some other file in `/etc` (that was in, or before, 2000).

Comment: OK, so you're assuming that profile always sources the files in `profile.d` (which seems to be a very reasonable assumption). However, if you need to make changes in `profile` in order to source `profile.d` the same argument about being overwritten by a new version stands.

Comment: @terdon I assume that it (or something similar) is already there, that is why I indicated to check, not to add the code. Once a distro does that (e.g. Ubuntu at least since 8.04), they are likely to leave it in for future updates.