# The PyCharm command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I knew how to set up a command in `$PATH`, but I need someone refresh my mind. In fact, I have the '.sh' script `/home/jeremie/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin/pycharm.sh` that I want to put in `$PATH`. My purpose is to be able to use `pycharm` as a command. I figure out that the first step is `export PATH = $PATH:Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin/pycharm.sh`, but It is unclear.

How to convert `/home/jeremie/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin/pycharm.sh` to obtain the `pycharm` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PATH` is a list of colon (`:`) separated directories where the shell will search to find the file you're calling.  Therefore you would need to add `/home/jeremie/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin` to it and not include the file itself.

If you want to change the name from `pycharm.sh` to `pycharm`, you would either rename or copy it, or preferably make a symbolic link to it such as:

```
ln -s /home/jeremie/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin/pycharm.sh /home/jeremie/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin/pycharm
```

Note that your expression `export PATH = $PATH:Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin/pycharm.sh` will fail because of extra spaces surrounding the equal sign (`=`).  Properly corrected, it should be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/jeremie/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin
```

Comment: Why that new command is not permanent in `$PATH`? What can I do to make this parmanent?

Comment: That's another question which has been asked multiple times.  Look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74076/167583